# Python Opencv VideoCapture takes at most 1 argument (2 given)

Tags: python, opencv, webcam, video-capture

I want to use VideoCaptureAPIs(cv2.CAP_DSHOW) to adjust my resolution.
link: https://reurl.cc/NXZgp6

Because I can not change the scale into 16:9.
It's always 4:3 although I set the resolution as 1280*720. It doesn't work but giving me a image like this.

[image: Both side are black LUL]

The webcam is Logitech C992 Pro stream webcam.
And I have already upgrade the driver.

Do anyone knows how to fix it?

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1,cv2.CAP_DSHOW)

cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1280)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720)

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And the error code is below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/VisualCode/Weight Scale2/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1,cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
TypeError: VideoCapture() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)
```

Comment: I have the same camera too and now tested with the same code. Actually, nothing is wrong with your code. Also [VideoCapture](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#ad890d4783ff81f53036380bd89dd31aa) can take 2 arguments. It shouldn't throw such an error. Which version of opencv  are you using?

Comment: `apiPreference` was introduced in OpenCV 3.1, so make sure you are using at least that version.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'm using Python3.6.12 and try two version of opencv:3.4.2 and 4.5.1.48 but end up the same result. What's your version?

Comment: I think you should update your OpenCV version, most probably your version of opencv is 3.4.2 [source](https://answers.opencv.org/question/237276/resolution-issues-when-setting-video-capture-device/)

Comment: Can you try to change resolution from windows camera application whether is it possible or not?

Comment: Yes I use the software Logitech Capture, and it's nothing wrong. Maybe the problem is on my computer.

Comment: Weirdo. The last recommendation  is to check `pip list` and be sure there is no conflict with the version and one package for opencv.(never install multiple packages like `opencv-python` and `opencv-python-contrib`).

Comment: It finally work out. By using python3.7.9 with opencv4.5.1.48. I'm not sure whether it depends on the python version or not

Comment: @CodingPeter Peter if you already solved your problem, please try to answer it so the people meeting same problem in future can try your method. Please try to answer in a clear and appropriate way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Solution]
Okay, so I solved the problem by using python3.7.9 and opencv 4.5.1.48 and it works!! I think there are some definition conflicts  when using opencv with some versions of python, like 3.6 and 3.8.

So I just upgraded the python environment and opencv version:

```
pip  install --upgrade opencv-python==4.5.1.48
```

Hope this answer helps.